# Filtering the first item of each row when using flexwrap

Tags: react-native

[image]

```
<View style={styles.categories}>
  _.map(categories, (item) => {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.userCategories>
        {'• ' + item}
      </Text>
    )
  })
</View>
...
categories: {
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  userCategories: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: colors.text.secondary,
    fontWeight: '400',
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
```

So I want to remove the • at the first of each line. So removing • at `Brand`, `Distributor`, `Logistics`, `Manufacturer`. Please let me know how can I fix this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just found answer and here's my solution.

```
                  const x = _.get(tagPositions, type + '.x', 0)
                    const y = _.get(tagPositions, type + '.y', 0)
                    let checkFirst = false
                    if(x) {
                      // console.log(type, x, y)
                      const values = Object.values(tagPositions)
                      checkFirst = values.filter(item => (item.y === y && item.x < x)).length === 0
                      console.log(type,x, y, checkFirst)
                    }
                    return (
                      <Text onLayout={e => {
                        if(x === 0 && y === 0) {
                          const temp = {...tagPositions}
                          temp[type] = {...e.nativeEvent.layout}
                          this.setState({tagPositions: temp})
                        }
                      }} style={styles.userCategories}>
                        {(checkFirst ? '  ' : '• ') + categories.categories.supplyChain[type]}
                      </Text>
                    )
                  })
```